# How to compute svd gradient if we replace tf.svd() by np.linalg.svd()

Tags: tensorflow, svd

`tf.svd()` function run slowly, i replace it with `np.linalg.svd()` by `tf.py_func()`. However, its gradient is None.

For example:

As to a matrix `A`, it is:

`A = U*S*T`

To compute `U`,`S`, `T`. We can use `tf.svd()` in tensowflow, which means:

```
S = f(A)
U = f(A)
T = f(A)
```

In tensorflow, we can compute `S`, `U`, `T` by:

```
S, U, T = tf.svd(A)
```

and get gradient.

```
gradient = tf.gradients(S,[A])
```

However, we replace `tf.svd()` with `np.linalg.svd()` by `tf.py_func()`. Because `tf.svd()` run very slowly. However, `tf.gradients(S,[A])` return `NoneType`.

So how to compute `tf.gradients(S,[A])` if we replace `tf.svd()` by `np.linalg.svd()`.